# List Unique EC2 volume snapshots by querying user-defined tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a use case where i take EC2 volume snapshots for multiple volumes at regular intervals of time and i also have 2 custom tags defined for snapshots. Lets call tags t1 and t2 respectively. t1 contains namespace value while t2 contains volumeID.

e.g: (s==snapshotID, n==Namespace, v==volumeID, time'x'==Time when the snapshot was taken)

```
s1->n1->v1->time1
s2->n1->v1->time2
s3->n1->v2->time1
s4->n1->v2->time2
```

I now want to list the snapshots first based on t1 and then, i want to list the latest unique snapshot for all volumes.

The output should be:

```
s2->n1->v1->time2
s4->n1->v2->time2
```

I am new to AWS CLI and wanted to seek help on how best to go forward with the task in hand.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should hopefully do what you want: https://github.com/thisaaronm/aws-latest-tagged-snaps

I tested it on my own account and it appears to work the way you described.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a bash script implementation of the same somewhere ?

Comment: Not sure. I wrote that myself (with a little help here and there from Google), so you can look around. But given that you're using the AWS CLI, I assumed you already had Python installed.

Comment: No problem. I can translate the same into a bash script and get things working. Thanks for the script again!

Comment: No problem, but just keep in mind that if you have bash and the AWS CLI, there's a strong chance you have Python (since the AWS CLI requires Python on Linux and macOS), so unless there's a strong reason for needing it in bash, or you somehow have bash and the AWS CLI but not Python 3.6 (not sure how that'd work), then you may want to just try to run it first before putting in the extra work. But your call. Just trying to help.

Comment: Yup.  That was the plan. Will give this script a try and then will try to have the same in bash script.